# What's a good method to solve for scalars in a vector equality?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

For example, what's a good way to solve for $c_1$, $c_2$ and $c_3$ in:

$$ c_1(1,-1,0) + c_2(3,2,1) + c_3(0,1,4) = (-1,1,19) $$

Comment: This is a basic problem in linear algebra. The key phrase here is [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination), which you can read about on Wikipedia, for example.

Comment: Yeah, we gotta start somewhere :)

Comment: I didn't have a proper public preparation that would allow me to see the connection.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you really have is a system of linear equations. You can express this in the form $Ax=b$ for matrix $A$ and vectors $x,b$.

In the case of your example:
 $$\left(\begin{matrix} 1 & 3 &0 \\
 -1&2&1\\
 0&1&4\\ \end{matrix} \right)
 \left(\begin{matrix}c_1\\ c_2\\ c_3\end{matrix}\right) = \left(\begin{matrix}-1\\1\\19\end{matrix}\right)$$

You can solve this by [Gaussian Elimination](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gaussian_elimination). A special case is when $A$ is invertible we have $x=A^{-1}b$.

Comment: Please see comment below to previous answer.

Answer (score 1):

Solve it like you would any system of equations.  This is a system of three equations with three unknowns:

$c_1 + 3c_2 = -1$

$-c_1 + 2c_2 + c_3 = 1$

$c_2 + 4c_3 = 19$

There are many ways to go about solving this type of system, including substitution and elimination techniques.

Comment: I think I failed to make the connection of the poor quality of science education in public school, even though I went to the Beacon School in New York City, we were placed in streams. There was a gifted stream, which made eveything sound good, and then there was a middle-class stream and a poor stream. I was in the poor stream, and one of our teachers just came back from disability, and would give us simple worksheets and read her newspaper. Being kids, we thought we had it easy and didn't realize how this would impact our pursuits later. I wish I'd known Computer Science was a subset of math.

Comment: Unfortunately, she is a community college professor now. It's an ongoing shame that is systemic, and she being aware of this is either giving up or exploiting it for her own best interests: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qHLfs.png